# Classification and regression tree at once

Tags: regression, classification, categorical-data

I would like to understand if there is a machine learning algorithm that is able to handle both, polytomous (categorical) and continuous independent variables at once, to predict a continuous dependent variable.

For instance, the dataset would look something like:

- Independent variables: Age (non categorical), Sex (categorical), Native country (categorical), Work hours per week (non categorical).
- Dependent variable: Income.

If there is not such an algorithm to predict using at once categorical and non categorical variables, which approach you would suggest to solve this problem?

Many thanks.

Comment: Many software packages reduce continuous information to ordinal buckets, sometimes deciles depending on the algorithm.

Comment: The ``Classification`` and ``Regression`` part of ``Classification Tree`` and ``Regression Tree`` refer to the type of the _Dependent variable_, their output, and not their input. They are both capable of handling different type of input variable. However, you should check what assumption the algorithm/implementation you use makes (for exemple, linear regression assumes a linear relationship between the inputs and the outputs).

Comment: Most supervised learning algorithms can use both categorical and continuous variables. You'll just have to create dummy variables for the categorical variables before fitting.

Comment: Thanks everyone. It was helpful and now I understand where was my conceptual mistake. I will use dummy variables in the input of my tree for the categorical variables.